# How to get Nginx to verify MIT personal certificates?

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate

I run a webapp with users at MIT.  They have asked whether the webapp could authenticate users (perhaps as a second factor) by their MIT personal certificates.  I have tried but I can't get it to work.

I downloaded the MIT CA certificate from the [MIT certificates page](https://ist.mit.edu/certificates/guide) – see the link "Get MIT CA (Certificate Authority)" near the bottom of the page – and converted it to PEM format.

Then I uploaded the certificate to the webserver, configured Nginx like this, and reloaded it:

```
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/mitca.pem;
ssl_verify_client optional;
ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

When an MIT user visited the webapp, their browser prompted them to choose a certificate.  They chose their MIT personal one.  Then Nginx showed an error page: "400 Bad Request / The SSL certificate error".  The error log contained this:

```
client SSL certificate verify error: (21:unable to verify the first certificate) while reading client request headers
```

Error 21 (or X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE) means "No signatures could be verified because the chain contains only one certificate and it is not self signed" according to [openssl's docs](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/doc/man3/X509_STORE_CTX_get_error.pod).

Presumably the "chain" refers to the MIT CA certificate?

I thought the MIT CA certificate was self-signed because of this result:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile mitca.pem mitca.pem
mitca.pem: OK
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you try `ssl_trusted_certificate` instead of `ssl_client_certificate`?

Comment: I don't want to try something unless I'm confident it will work because I don't want to alienate my users.  Also, this [question](https://serverfault.com/q/938269) suggests it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With nginx, you have to concatenate the certificate chain and the cert into one file, in this case at `/etc/nginx/certs/mitca.pem`

This can be done on a UNIX CLI with the following command:

```
cat your-signed.crt ca-cert-chain.crt > /etc/nginx/certs/mitca.pem
```

...then restart nginx. You can use `nginx -t` beforehand to make sure that the syntax is OK and the certs are valid (and nginx will restart)

Comment: I think you're talking about how to chain together certs for a server, but Andy is talking about using certs as an authentication mechanism (different problem)

Comment: @TimDiggins That's right.  I want Nginx to check whether a certificate presented by a web browser to Nginx has been signed by the certificate authority (mitca.pem).